# Make a seamless transition between different urls

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have two pages located on different urls: Home and, for example, Contact. I have some fancy CSS3 effects on Home page and a link to Contact page.

When I click on Contact page link, I want to slide some Home page elements off the page, or make them transparent or something else, then I just let the browser load Contact page, but I want to make this transition as seamless as possible. Ideally, to achieve the effect of a one-page site, where I can easily show and hide page elements.

How to do it the best way?

Comment: Start fetching the Contact page already when the Home page elements are fading out. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: unless you already have the content loaded but hidden you will have to have a loading sign for the user, otherwise they will click and nothing will seem to happen. so will that be seamless? possibly best to have all the content loaded (if it is small)

Answer (score 3):

- Load the content with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)
- Use the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to change the URL to one which will load the contact page by default
- Use CSS [Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions) / [Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) to move the content about